# How to Display JSON output in .net webservice like array inside array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, web-services

My Code is Below:

```
public class WS_Login : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        DAL.dbOperation dboperation = new DAL.dbOperation();
        dboperation.AddParameter("@EUserID", userName);
        dboperation.AddParameter("@CompID", Convert.ToString(balUserlogin.m_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CompanyID"]));
        DataSet ds = dboperation.getDataSet("Mobile_sp_tbl_Employee_Select_Fullinfo");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "EmployeePhoto", "EmployeeID", "EmpName", "EmployeementDate", "EDateOfBirth", "StateName", "BranchName", "CategoryName", "SubCatName", "DepartmentName", "DesignationName", "PaycaderName", "EProbation", "ECompanyEmail" };
            DataTable dt = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);

            var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row[col] = row[col].ToString();
                    dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
                }
                list.Add(dict);
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list));
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is Generating output like this:

```
[{"EmployeePhoto":"1009-employee.jpg","EmployeeID":"1009","EmpName":"JOHN PATEL","EmployeementDate":"01 Aug 2003","EDateOfBirth":"02 Jan 1979","StateName":"Gujarat","BranchName":"Maintenance","CategoryName":"Staff","SubCatName":"Technical","DepartmentName":"Electrical and Electronics","DesignationName":"MANAGER (MAINT.)","PaycaderName":"M4","EProbation":"0","ECompanyEmail":"abc@manager.co"}]
```

But I want to generate output like this:

```
{
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  "phoneNumber": [
    {
      "location": "home",
      "code": 44
    }
  ]
}
```

Array inside array. so how can I generate output like this using **var list = new List>();** in .NET webservice

Answer (score 0):

There is no array inside array in your example. Curly brackets are for structures. For arrays, JSON uses square brackets. If you want structure inside structure, simply define class which contains another class. If you really want array inside array, define class that contains array.

```
public class A
{
  public int aa { get; set; }
  public int ab { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
  public int ba { get; set; }
  public A bb { get; set; }
}
```

This will encode into "structure in structure".  And this

```
public class A
{
  public int aa { get; set; }
  public int ab { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
  public int ba { get; set; }
  public A[] bb { get; set; }
}
```

will give you "array inside structure".

```
public class C
{
  public int ca { get; set; }
  public B[] cb { get; set; }
}
```

Finally this one would give you "array inside array inside structure".